# Take word out of list if it is the same as string variable name

Tags: python

I want the user to write the name of a fruit, and then I want print out the name of another fruit from my list. However, I don't want to print out the same fruit name as the user put in. I have written my code below and used a while-loop that will run as long as the "botAnswer" and "user_word" match, but the code doesn't seem to work like I intended.

```
user_word = input()
word_list = ["apple", "banana", "plum", "peach"]
n = 0
while n < 1:
   botAnswer = random.choice(word_list)
   if botAnswer == user_word:
      n = 0
   else:
      n = 1
```

Comment: What's the output you are getting? It seems fine on my end.

Comment: "code doesn't seem to work like I intended" -- please explain.

Comment: You need to print the `botAnswer` after the loop. Code works correctly

Comment: `random.choice([w for w in word_list if w != user_word])`

Comment: BTW, don't use `0/1` for binary choices, use `False/True`. Even better, use `while True:` for the loop, and  a `break` statement when you want the loop to end, instead of a variable.

Comment: Will add print botAnswer after, and change it to false/true. I think that the part of the code I showed does work and that the problem I face must be elsewhere in my code, since you guys think that it seems fine

Answer (score 1):

You can get two different elements from `word_list`, and use the second element if the first is taken, using `random.choices()`:

```
def my_func():
    user_word = input('?: ')
    word_list = ["apple", "banana", "plum", "peach"]
    possible = random.choices(word_list, k=2)
    bot_answer = possible[0] if (possible[0] != user_word) else possible[1]
    print(f"Chosen word is {bot_answer}.\n")
```

Example in action, using `random.seed()` to make sure the random result is the same between calls:

```
>>> random.seed(3)
>>> my_func()
?: banana
Chosen word is apple.

>>> random.seed(3)
>>> my_func()
?: apple
Chosen word is plum.

>>> random.seed(3)
>>> my_func()
?: plum
Chosen word is apple.
```

Comment: may fail if `word_list` contains 2 copies of the `user_word`

Answer (score 1):

A fairly clear solution is to use a list comprehension filter out choices equivalent to the input string.

```
user_word = input()
word_list = ["apple", "banana", "plum", "peach"]
bot_answer = random.choice([word for word in word_list if word != user_word])
```